# Egg substitute for cookie-flavor syrup

Tags: eggs, sugar, milk, vanilla

My goal is to transfer the taste of chocolate chip cookies to milk, as a milk drink.

I normally bake cookies with eggs of course. But the taste I want to achieve is exactly the unbaked mix of brown sugar, white sugar, butter, vanilla extract and egg in the stand mixer. Unforunately, I can't have raw egg in a milk drink, can I?

What can I substitute for egg in this situation? The egg adds creaminess and some runniness. When I DID try it on cool milk, it was perfect -- maybe a hint more of vanilla or chocolate sauce.

Thank you!

Comment: Is your concern about using egg related to food safety, or to longer-term storage of the finished product?

Comment: Presumably some sort of pasteurized egg product would work? Or treat the egg however they prepare it for egg nog? I've never made it, so, other than booze, I'm not sure what (if anything) makes nog safe to drink.

Comment: The taste/aroma we associate with eggs in a mixture ... is mostly that of sulphuric compounds. Using a strong kala namak in the right amount might be enough to create the illusion...

Comment: @logophobe: yes on both counts, moreso for food safety.

Comment: @Catija like mayonnaise? I'm not familiar with a lot of products...

Comment: What about glycerine? Do you think that would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider going with [pasteurized eggs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasteurized_eggs) (if you can find them whole) or a pasteurized egg product (a common US brand is "Egg Beaters").

> Pasteurized eggs are eggs that have been pasteurized in order to reduce the risk of food-borne illness in dishes that are not cooked or are only lightly cooked. They may be sold as liquid egg products or pasteurized in the shell.
>
> The 2013 United States Food and Drug Administration Food Code defines regular shell eggs as a potentially hazardous food, i.e., “a food that requires time/temperature control for safety (TCS) to limit pathogenic microorganism growth or toxin formation.
>
> Because of the risk of food-borne illness caused by Salmonella bacteria that may be present in raw eggs, the U.S. Department of Agriculture requires a safe-handling advisory statement on all packages of raw shell eggs that are not treated to destroy Salmonella as follows: "Safe Handling Instructions: To prevent illness from bacteria: Keep eggs refrigerated, cook eggs until yolks are firm, and cook foods containing eggs thoroughly."
>
> The FDA Food Code exempts pasteurized shell eggs from the definition of "time/temperature control for safe food” requirement to carry a safe handling advisory statement.
>
> **The U.S. Department of Agriculture also states, “In-shell pasteurized eggs may be used safely without cooking.**”

Your local grocer may sell in-shell pasteurized eggs but you'll probably find it easier to simply by them out of the shell in a carton like this:

[image: Egg Beaters]

Note that Egg Beaters brand is made without yolks, so it probably doesn't have the flavor you want, so be sure to read the packaging of the different brands... your best hope of duplicating the flavor without risking added chemicals is probably to find whole eggs.

---

All that being said, I don't think it would be a good idea for you to attempt to store this for any extended period of time, at longest, you should abide by the "sell by" date on the pasteurized egg packaging.

Comment: Thank you, this is a wonderful answer. I'm marking it, since I may be able to circumvent microbial issues by caramelizing my mixture for a bit.